# Acessar os dados de um Array que recebe 2 Arrays

Tags: php, cakephp

Digamos que tenho um Array `$testes` que recebe 2 Arrays `$variavel1` e `$variavel2`. Então eu faço `$this->set('testes', $testes)` para utilizar na view.

Na View como eu acesso os valores de `$variavel1` e `$variavel2` ? Fiz um foreach e tentei `$testes['$variavel1']['campo']`, mas só dá um `Undefined Index` na `$variavel1`.

Exemplo, como acessar os dados deste Array?

```
Array (
    [0] => Array (
        [ProcuraProdutoPedOnline] => Array (
            [cd_familia] => 3
            [ds_familia] => ACESSORIOS
        )
    )
    [1] => Array (
        [ProcuraProdutoPedOnline] => Array (
            [cd_familia] => 1
            [ds_familia] => CALCADOS
        )
    )
)
```

E

```
Array (
    [0] => Array (
        [VwEstPedOnline] => Array (
            [cd_seq_pedido] => 2034
        )
    )
    [1] => Array (
        [VwEstPedOnline] => Array (
            [cd_seq_pedido] => 2038
        )
    )
)
```

`$testes` está recebendo assim : `$testes = array($cdSeqPeds, $familias);`

Answer (score 4):

Para percorrer o `array`, faça assim:

```
$array = array("0" => array ( "ProcuraProdutoPedOnline" => array(
                              "cd_familia" => 3,
                              "ds_familia" => "ACESSORIOS")
                             ),
                "1" => array ( "ProcuraProdutoPedOnline" => array(
                               "cd_familia" => 1,
                               "ds_familia" => "CALCADOS")
                             )
               );

foreach ($array as $indices) {
    foreach($indices as $pedidos){
        foreach ($pedidos as $chave => $pedido){
            echo "$chave = $pedido\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Para acessar diretamente um valor, é necessário especificar o índice, o *subarray* e a chave. Assim:

```
echo $array[0]["ProcuraProdutoPedOnline"]["ds_familia"];
```

[Ver `demonstração`](http://ideone.com/s6mBLx)

Answer (score 1):

Tem a resposta na sua própria pergunta. Se existem dois vetores dentro de um, você primeiro precisa identificar em qual dos dois está o seu objeto. Claro que é importante verificar se realmente o índice existe.

Por exemplo, para o primeiro objeto do seu primeiro exemplo:

```
$testes[0]['ProcuraProdutoPedOnline']['cd_familia']
```

E para o segundo objeto:

```
$testes[1]['ProcuraProdutoPedOnline']['cd_familia']
```

Dentro de um `foreach`, por exemplo:

```
foreach ($testes as $obj) {
    // $obj['ProcuraProdutoPedOnline']['cd_familia']
}
```

Naturalmente, no `foreach` não precisa já que ele faz o laço sobre os elementos dentro de `$testes`.

Comment: Eu já tentei dessa forma, ele só printa o 2034 devido o [0], e identifica ProcuraProdutoPedOnline como undefined, e cd_familia null.